# VC++ programatically exclude specific lines of code

Tags: c++, conditional-compilation

I didn't found any reference to what I'm looking for so probably best is to ask here.
Lets say I want to have 2 version of my program.

Now I do something like:

```
#define MY_VER 0 //0 or 1 depending on which version I want to compile

Function1();
if(MY_VER)
Function2();  //It will run only if MY_VER is set
```

Now I have lots of code as such, but even when I compile it with MY_VER=0 some of the strings in "my" functions are still in exe. How to programaticaly exclude some of the lines, so they are completly unexistant when I want it to be like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious possibility would be to use the preprocessor:

```
#if MY_VER
Function2();
#endif
```

Less obvious (but usually equally effective) is to just turn on the optimizer. What you have there is dead code, which most compilers can identify and remove quite effectively.

Comment: Do use `/OPT:REF /OPT:ICF` to aggressively eliminate unused stuff in VC++.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the pre-processor "if":

```
#if(MY_VER)
```

Note the "`#`". Don't forget to close with `#endif`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the preprocessor to remove them, so the compiler doesn't even see those lines.

Use `#if MY_VER` ... `#endif`

If you want to be totally sure that some functions aren't included, use conditional compilation not only for the calls to those functions, but for the function definitions themselves.